# Handling bad XML from HttpRequest

Tags: android, xml-parsing, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a problem with XML parser - I receive a XML via:

```
public String executeHttp() {
    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
        resp = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();

        return EntityUtils.toString(ent, "UTF-8");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then give it to the parser:

```
Xml.parse(this.executeHttp(), this);
```

which works just fine, it parses what I need and gosh, life is great...however.
I have just found out that I get some serious exceptions on real devices, where the internet connection isn't that great thanks to the fact that my parser isn't handling situations such as: "I didn't get a proper XML.", "That XML didn't make it really through." or "Uhm..this XML doesn't make any sense, really."

I believe it has to be somewhere in the parser. Any good advices where this "XML verification" should be placed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is to *validate* the XML data you received from your HTTP request against an XML Schema file (xsd document). Seeing as you've never done this before, I would start [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/) and first create a valid schema, and then move on to the Java validation portion.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! It was right in front of me the whole time!

```
try {
        Xml.parse(this.executeHttp(), this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.execute(XMLchoice, objId, selectedTime);
    }
```

Instead of taking down the whole app, I'm catching an exception and repeating downloading the XML file until it's complete.